# Deleting in SailGraph

Tags: graph, neo4j, tinkerpop

I am trying to delete a vertex in SailGraph. This works locally but not on the server. On the server the underlying neo4j database is left inconsistent.

```
    graph = GraphFactory.createGraph(config.get("type").getAsString(),
            name, dbpath);
    sail = new GraphSail<KeyIndexableGraph>(graph);
    sailGraph = new SailGraph(sail);
    reasoner = new ForwardChainingRDFSInferencer(
            new GraphSail<KeyIndexableGraph>(graph));
```

This is what i use to initialise then I load an RDF

```
       public static void loadRDF(InputStream is, String baseURI, String format,
                 sailGraph.loadRDF(is, baseURI, format, baseGraph);
```

To remove I use

```
         Vertex vertex = sailGraph.getVertex(uri);
         vertex.remove();
```

Locally it works on the server it goes past the remove step but the vertex is still there. No exceptions or anything. I have set the permissions on the database directory to allow writing but still nothing. Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Noticed that calling remove from a different thread it does not work.

Comment: What do you mean locally vs. "the server".

Comment: Can you show how you set up your dbpath ? And isn't there a `Neo4jGraph` needed in beetween somewhere?